# How to make a score in a dynamic textfield display on another frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'am trying to make a scoring system by using a timer so that it work on the basis that as the player keeps on going the timer/score keeps on going up and I got that to work with this code.

```
var nCount:Number = 0;
var myScore:Timer = new Timer(10, nCount);
score_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myScore.start();
myScore.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void{
    nCount++;
    score_txt.text = nCount.toString();
}
```

However say for example the player crashes I want the game to remember the score and then display it on another frame where I have a game over screen so that it shows the final score to the player and this is the part that I have no idea how to do. Any help would be appreciated.
Many Thanks

Comment: just use score_txt.text = nCount.toString(); where the score_txt will be the new textfield in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify objects on "another frame". You can only modify objects on the current frame. The frames simply represent state that is baked into the SWF to be actualized when the timeline reaches those frames; you cannot change SWF frame data at runtime. You can only change the resulting objects once those frames are constructed by the player.

What you can do is store your score in a variable (available across all frames) and simply set the correct text objects when you are on those frames.

For your code, you simply need to only set the `nCount` to 0 when the SWF loads (or you want to reset it), and set the `score_txt` immediately on the frame it exists. For example, you could do it like this:

```
// Don't initialize a value, that would overwrite 
// it every time this frame is visited
var nCount:Number;

// Only the first time, when the value is NaN, set the score to 0
if(isNaN(nCount)){
    nCount = 0;
}

// Immediately show the current score text
score_txt.text = nCount.toString();

// The rest stays the same
var myScore:Timer = new Timer(10, nCount);
score_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myScore.start();
myScore.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void{
    nCount++;
    score_txt.text = nCount.toString();
}
```